# What is the most clear way to link to git souce code from a wiki in Visual Studio Online?

Tags: azure

Within a visual studio online (Azure DevOps?) wiki I want to link to a source code directory, because its relevant for the text of the wiki document.

Linking to other wiki documents within Visual studio online is done by right-clicking on the document explorer side-bar and clicking "Copy Page Path".  This will copy a nice link with text to the clipboard.  The actual link itself is more concise than when visting to the document's page and copying it from the address bar.
[image: Copy Page Path example]
However, I can't seem to find the equivalent in Visual Studio Online's git repository's for the same project.  I would like to be able to produce a nicely formatted link to the git directories as I do when I'm linking between wiki pages.

**Is there a way to get a nice link url for a Visual Studio online git directory other than by copying the address bar's url when visiting the page for that directory?**

The address bar version of things usually has tons of query string parameters that look ugly and are hard to read.

Answer (score 1):

you can try to use the `Clone` url for the Git repository.

It looks like `https://dev.azure.com/{tenant}/{project}/_git/{repository}` and can be used in the browser too.